# Angular directive to move between inputs and format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that does several things to a group of six single digit text input:

1 Capitalize the input if the user enters a lower case alphabet character
2. Reject any non alphabet character
3. Move back one input if user presses backspace, and delete the previous character if the user presses backspace twice.

Items 1 and 2 work, but item 3 doesn't work as expected. Right now, backspace goes to previous input AND deletes the input in one step.

Here is the UPDATED code. How do I get #3 working as described?

[Here's a Fiddle (caps not working in the Fiddle but works locally for me)](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/).

```
<input class="code-char" type="text" maxlength="1" ng-model="code[0]" capitalize>
<input class="code-char" type="text" maxlength="1" ng-model="code[1]" capitalize>
<input class="code-char" type="text" maxlength="1" ng-model="code[2]" capitalize>

.directive('capitalize', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
        var charString = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''); //to reject non-alphabet characters
        var shouldDelete = false;
        var shouldMoveBack = true;
        element.bind('keyup', function(event) {
          var key = event.keyCode;
          if(key === 8) {
            if(shouldDelete == true) {
              shouldDelete = false;
              element[0].value ='';
            } else {
              shouldDelete = true;
              if(!scope.$first && shouldMoveBack == true) {
                element[0].previousElementSibling.focus();
                shouldMoveBack == false;
              } else {
                shouldMoveBack == true;
              }
            }
          } else {
             if(charString > '') element[0].nextElementSibling.focus();
          }
        });
        var capitalized = charString.toUpperCase();
        if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return capitalized;
      }
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
      capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: it deletes the input because you set the `value=''`.  There isn't a way to know if the user pressed the key twice in a row from a **single** `keyup` event.....

Comment: I added a conditional `shouldMoveBack` so cursor would not move back to the previous input unless it was deleted on a prior backspace `keyup`. However it still jumps back on every backspace `keyup`.

Comment: I guess I need to detect if the cursor moved forward into an input or backed into it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing on the previous sibling for the first case , You could prevent the default behaviour of backspace by doing `event.preventDefault()` and create a keypress event with keyCode of left arrow and trigger it manually for achieving the first case of #3 . For the second case , you could keep a counter to see if backspace is pressed for the second time and trigger the default behaviour. Check the below sample .

```
    var count = 0;
    var leftArrow = $.Event("keyup");
    leftArrow.which = 37;//37 being the keycode of left arrow

    element.bind('keyup', function (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        // 37 , 8
        if (key === 8) {// if it is backspace
            count++;
            if (count > 1) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                // prevent the default behaviour
                event.preventDefault();
                // create a left arrow keypress event
                element.triggerHandler(leftArrow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Conceptually this makes sense, but generates an error: `element.trigger is not a function`

Comment: Left arrow does not move cursor to previous input. Back tab does but the cursor goes to previous input only for a split second then bounces back. I still think this method will work so I am staying on this path...

Comment: If I am right it should be `element.triggerHandler(leftArrow)` referring https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: `triggerHandler` generates no error but cursor does not move. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilbiscuit/L18ckcrd/3/)

Comment: Possibly [`.which` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)....